# extjs 4 How too keep combobox in grid cell

Tags: extjs, datagrid, combobox, extjs4

I've seen similar questions go unanswered elsewhere. I want to have a combobox in a column with two options (ASC, DEC) in it. I want it to show up in each row, or at least have its value show up when it's not selected.

I know that its not a 'good idea' to render a combobox in each row, but in this case I know I will have a maximum of about 20 rows, so it shouldn't be a huge deal. If this can't be done I want to have the selected value from the combobox show. Currently I just have the comboboxes appearing when I click a row, which doesn't make much sense since you can't see your selection unless you are making it. What is the solution to this?

Also, I want to get rid of the change and cancel buttons that pop up when I click a row, I just want to be able to edit the cell with the combobox, and have it automatically change/save.

Answer (score 8):

You can set a default value for the `combo`.

That should then get that rendered at startup.

Use cell `renderer` to `render` the `displayField` of the `combo` into your grid. Following a working example that can be poster in one of the API code boxes.

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/we3Vu/)**

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'id'],
    data: {
        'items': [{
            "name": "Lisa",
            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-111-1224",
            "id": 0
        }, {
            "name": "Bart",
            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1234",
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "name": "Homer",
            "email": "home@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244",
            "id": 2
        }, {
            "name": "Marge",
            "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1254",
            "id": 3
        }]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

// the renderer. You should define it within a namespace
var comboBoxRenderer = function(combo) {
    return function(value) {
        var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
        var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
        return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField));
    };
}
// the combo store
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: ["value", "text"],
    data: [
        [1, "Option 1"],
        [2, "Option 2"]
    ]
});
// the edit combo
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: store,
    valueField: "value",
    displayField: "text"
});


// demogrid
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        editor: 'textfield'
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'id',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        editor: combo,
        renderer: comboBoxRenderer(combo)
    }],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Via what config: I have value: 'ASC'  and that isn't doing the trick

Comment: @Bbb I am on it... hopefully get it running... ;)

Comment: @Bbd this works. Use a renderer that uses the displayfield of the combo to render the display value an the combo to edit.

Comment: This is exactly how I do it too

Comment: I adapted this to be more MVC friendly:`code`                                    renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                    if (value == '') return '';`code` 
                  
                    var combo = this.columns[colIndex].getEditor();
                    var sto = Ext.getStore(combo.store);
                    var idx = sto.find(combo.valueField, value);
                    var rec = sto.getAt(idx);
                    return (rec === null || rec === undefined ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField));
                }

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    header: 'Your header',
    dataIndex: 'your Column',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: yourStore,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'Your Display..',
        valueField: 'Your Value'
    }
```