# ExtJS 4.2 grid cellediting how to bind column value with combo display value

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a grid with cellediting plugin.

One of my columns is a `int` field which represents a value in a combo store when editing the cell.

I want to know how can I have this column to show the displayfield instead of the value before I edit the cell.

Here are the images for reference:

[image]

The values 2,0,0 etc are my "accesstype" field that is an int.

If I click the cell to edit that why I get:

[image]

And If I select a value then instead of showing the text I get again the int value.

[image]

> How can I show the display field instead of the value field?

Comment: Use a column renderer to lookup the value.

Comment: Is the only way? Does that affect any performance?

Comment: You are looking for [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319225/extjs-4-how-too-keep-combobox-in-grid-cell/12319286#12319286)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ease of access here's the answer from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319225/extjs-4-how-too-keep-combobox-in-grid-cell/12319286#12319286):

You can set a default value for the combo. That should then get that rendered at startup.

Use cell renderer to render the displayField of the combo into your grid. Following a working example that can be poster in one of the API code boxes

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/we3Vu/)**

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone', 'id'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224","id": 0},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234","id": 1},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244","id": 2},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254","id": 3}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

// the renderer. You should define it within a namespace
var comboBoxRenderer = function(combo) {
  return function(value) {
    var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
    var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
    return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField) );
  };
}
// the combo store
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
  fields: [ "value", "text" ],
  data: [
    [ 1, "Option 1" ],
    [ 2, "Option 2" ]
  ]
});
// the edit combo
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  store: store,
  valueField: "value",
  displayField: "text"
});


// demogrid
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'},
        {header: 'id', dataIndex: 'id', editor: combo, renderer: comboBoxRenderer(combo)}
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the config property 'valueField' for that combo,it will display the displayField value after the select of the value from the dropdown.